# Popping up a form after selecting image from file browser window

Tags: jquery, html

So Basically I have this form which uploads Images to server. What is happening right now is user clicks on : `<span><a href="#" id="snap">Photos</a></span>` id "snap" it pops up the form and then the usual stuff of uploading files happens fine.

```
<form id="fileupload" action="upload_backend.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*" id="dir_photo">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
             <span>Cancel</span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
            <span>Start upload</span>
        </button>
    <textarea placeholder="Say something about these photo..."></textarea>
```

What I want to do is when user clicks on id=snap the file browser window opens up and after the user selects file from the browsing window the above form shows up for processing the rest.

I had made the file browsing window open by using this code:

```
$('#snap').click(function(){ 
$('#dir_photo').trigger('click');
});
```

But the issue is the form is not opening up after selecting the file. How can I do that? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#dir_photo').change(function(e){
  $('#fileupload').fadeIn('slow');
//or if you want to submit instanly you can uncomment the following line too
      // e.target.form.submit();
});
```